# SOAP UI/Groovy missing error log

Tags: groovy, soapui, assertion

I encounter a strange behaviour in SOAP UI (pro) in a groovy script:

The context : 
I have a test case with several test steps, the two first steps are the interesting ones.
First step : Authentication, which returns a SOAP valid response that contains information I want to keep for further use. To do so, I use a groovy script in the second step.
Second step : groovy script that parses first step's response to extract relevant data.

Unfortunately, the network part is not stable and the server often fails to respond, so I added robustness (try/catch) in order to be able to stop testing if authentication is responseless.

In my groovy step I have the following part of code :

```
def response = 0
try
{
    response = new XmlParser().parseText(context.Response);
    //log.info response
} catch(NullPointerException e){
    log.info e
    testRunner.fail( "Authentication rejected" )
}
```

When the previous step have failed, if I run the step alone (from the test step edition) I end up with the following Script log:

```
Thu Nov 23 09:29:42 CET 2017:INFO:java.lang.NullPointerException
Thu Nov 23 09:29:42 CET 2017:ERROR:Failed with reason [Authentication rejected]
```

But when I launch the whole testCase and it fails for the same reason, I end up with :

```
Thu Nov 23 09:29:52 CET 2017:INFO:java.lang.NullPointerException
```

only.

Do anyone know why the ERROR log does not appear ?

I checked that, if I launch my testCase with the testRunner, the ERROR log appears.

Comment: i think you are comparing "log-output" with "script log". They are different things. When we run Groovy script log-output prints everything. But when you run at test case level, things does not come in log-output but script log. Let me know if it helps..

Comment: Ah ok, then in my case, I have the ERROR log in my log-output (groovy script only) which does not appear in my script log (when I launch my test case). Though I would have expected it ...

Answer (score 0):

In the `Script Assertion`, you can check if the response is null using below statement at the top.

```
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'
```

The above makes test step failure and error message is logged. Also it will part of the report if you are using junit report.

If authentication is failed, you might get `SOAP Fault`.

Comment: I don't get SOAP fault as it's a problem with the server, I don't even have a response.

Comment: the line you provide should display 'Response is empty or null' in my case ? in the Script log area ?

Comment: Provided test fails.

Comment: Ok, I was misusing it. Though it doesn't solve my problem if I launch the whole test case. The only error that appears is the one provoked by the server that does not respond, I still cannot see the error I set in the catch.

Comment: Not sure if got your question right, can you please elaborate the issue by editing the question with the use case?

Comment: From your edit, it is clear that you are using a Groovy Script test step with the code mentioned the question. However, it is evident from above answer that `Script Assertion` is used for Soap Request test step itself, and no separate groovy script test step. Would try to test and update by making the according change, please?

Comment: @A.Joly, have you got chance to try the above mentioned change and update please?

Comment: you mean setting the assertion in the previous step (authentication) ?

Comment: @A.Joly, yes, for the same step where you receive the response and no additional groovy script step required.

Comment: well, I already have assertions for that step (that do not generate additional log info) and I don't see how you can set the assertion in the step (there is a set of predefined assertions but none that you can write freely) ?

Comment: Looks there is confusion. You were getting `NullpointerException` which I saw in the question. That is because you were using incorrect for two reasons. 1. `context.Response` is not correct and see above answer to fix. 2. You do not need 2 nd step to parse and it can be done in `Script Assertion` of first step itself.

Comment: Indeed, there is a bit of confusion, sorry that I was not clear enough :)  I can actually stop processing when the error occurs, but I just wanted to log the information and then relaunch the authentication from the groovy script as, after several tries, it ends up working. Anyway it's not a blocking issue. thanks for your help.